# Changing permalink structure in WordPress requires redirect on old post links

Tags: wordpress, redirect, permalinks

Currently the permalink structure is this:

www.website.com/%postname%/

The new permalink structure is:

www.website.com/news/%postname%/

The change worked fine but old links using the original structure are all broken.

Is there a simple fix for this via .htaccess or even a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Just drop some regex in your .htaccess to handle the redirects like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/news/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```